# looping with two variable for htmltools::withTags?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, dt

```
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))
print(sketch)
```

and get

```
<table class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Species</th>
      <th colspan="2">Sepal</th>
      <th colspan="2">Petal</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th>Width</th>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th>Width</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Is there a way to loop this two lines if i have N columns?

```
  <th colspan="2">Sepal</th>
  <th colspan="2">Petal</th>
```

something like:

```
lapply(c('Sepal', 'Petal'), th)
```

But I could not figure out how to put in the "`colspan=2`" part.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Just add it in `lapply`: `lapply(c('Sepal', 'Petal'), th, colspan = 2)`

Comment: Thanks. I used the following to get same results: `lapply(c('Sepal', 'Petal'), function(x) th(colspan=2,x))`